# Powershell IE login automation unable to find the element by ID

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, authentication, automation, getelementbyid

Can someone knowledgeable in powershell tell me why I can't find the username input field using its ID "user_name"? I have tried this on other websites and it has worked but for this one it just refuses to find it. I also tried the IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName method and also IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName looking for things like "input" or even "div". Some div classes pop up but so many are missing there and I have no idea why its missing. Please show me the light.

```
#ID names
$IDuserName = "user_name"
$IDuserPass = "user_password"

$url = "https://isssupport.service-now.com/"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($URL)

While ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000} 

$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID($IDuserName).Value = $userName
```

Below is the HTML line for the Username input field

```
<input name="user_name" id="user_name" type="text" class="form-control" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: `$ie.Document.getElementByID($IDuserName).Value = $userName` usually works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is built with loads of javascript. If you try opening the page without javascript enabled in your browser you won't even see the login form. this seems to be the problem for IE/PowerShell to find the form and its elements.

However you could bring the Internet Explorer window into foreground and interact with the page using `Systems.Windows.Forms` like this:

```
#ID names
$IDuserName = "user_name"
$IDuserPass = "user_password"

$url = "https://isssupport.service-now.com/"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate($ie.Name)
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

$ie.navigate($url)

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('username');
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}');
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('password');
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}');
```

May I ask what the purpose of the script you are building is?

Best regards

Guenther

Comment: Thanks for that information Guenther, it would have taken me forever to find that out. I recently just joined the company and have been tasked to automate some of the service desk tasks so I am just trying to figure out the best language to automate it in. Seems like Powershell may not be the easiest language for this task.

Comment: Hi Michael, if you consider your question answered please mark it as such. Also if you are into automation I can recommend [sikulix](http://www.sikulix.com)